# Does "opening a file" mean loading it completely into memory?

Tags: c, objective-c

There's an AudioFileOpenURL function which opens an file. With AudioFileReadPackets that file is accessed to read packets. But one thing that stucks in my brain is: Does AudioFileOpenURL actually load the whole monster into memory? Or is that a lightweight operation?

So is it possible to read data from a file, only a specific portion, without having the whole terabytes of stuff in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does AudioFileOpenURL actually load the whole monster into memory?

No, it just gets you a file pointer.

> Or is that a lightweight operation?

Yep, fairly lightweight.  Just requires a filesystem lookup.

> So is it possible to read data from a file, only a specific portion, without having the whole terabytes of stuff in memory?

Yes, you can use `fseek` to go a certain point in the file, then `fread` to read it into a buffer (or `AudioFileReadBytes`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about objective-c, but with most languages you open the file, and that just gives you the ability to THEN access the contents with a READ operation.  In your case, you can perform a SEEK to move the file pointer to the desired location, then read the number of bytes you need.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't load the entire file into memory. "Opens a file" returns a handle to you allowing you to read from or write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

`AudioFileOpenURL` will [`open(2)`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/open.2.html) the file and read the necessary info (4096 bytes) to determine the audio type.

`open(2)` won't load the whole file into RAM.

(`AudioFileOpenURL` is a C API, not Objective-C.)